# Make sure two folders are identical on compressed zfs and ext4

Tags: filesystems, rsync, file-copy, zfs, checksum

### Summary

I have copied (`rsync --archive`) a folder from an `ext4` filesystem to a `zfs` file system with `compression on`. Now, I'm trying to verify that both folders are identical so that I can safely delete the source folder.

When re-running `rsync`, no additional bytes are transferred. So, rsync is convinced that both folders are identical.

However, using `du`, `du -b`, or `md5sum` yield different results for both folders.

How can I convince myself that both folders are identical before deleting the source folder?

### Examples

I've uploaded a [test folder `883`](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hgxhcqr5baykibf/AAABrPu5CyBNOk3bEv_RhsUra?dl=0) containing four files.

```
fiedl@ext4 ▶ du 883
20  883
fiedl@zfs ▶ du 883
57  883

fiedl@ext4 ▶ du -s 883
20  883
fiedl@zfs ▶ du -s 883
57  883

fiedl@ext4 ▶ du -sb 883
4660    883
fiedl@zfs ▶ du -sb 883
570 883

fiedl@ext4 ▶ du 883/*
4   883/big_image001.gif
4   883/image001.gif
4   883/medium_image001.gif
4   883/thumb.png
fiedl@zfs ▶ du 883/*
10  883/big_image001.gif
10  883/image001.gif
10  883/medium_image001.gif
10  883/thumb.png

fiedl@ext4 ▶ tar -cf - 883 | md5sum
7c8a4ff31fdf594b04173789b23c7bb8  -
fiedl@zfs ▶ tar -cf - 883 | md5sum
f207dbadd75126665af300705774c97f  -
```

Comment: Can you please show some examples of how the output is different? Also, can you please provide a sample file so we can test it ourselves on our own ext4 and zfs installations?

Comment: Thanks, cryptarch, for your suggestion. I've added some examples. In the meantime, I may have found a workaround using a combination of `find`, `md5sum`, `sort`, and `diff`. Should I post this as an answer or should I wait for someone posting a proper way to do it?

Comment: If you think you have an answer, I reckon you should post it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `md5sum` and `diff`

Under the assumption that the observed differences are the results of different meta data and zfs compression, the respective `md5sum` of the individual files [should still be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6869901/2066546).

```
cd /path/to/ext4 && find . | xargs md5sum | sort > ~/md5sum-index-ext4
cd /path/to/zfs  && find . | xargs md5sum | sort > ~/md5sum-index-zfs
diff ~/md5sum-index-ext4 ~/md5sum-index-zfs
```

This workaround recursively lists all files within the directories using `find`, adds the `md5sum` for each file, `sort`s the results because `find` may return the contents in different order. Then the results for both folders can be compared. If they are identical, the `diff` is empty. Otherwise, the files with different binary content will show up in the `diff`.

#### `diff -r`

I was able to compare smaller folders directly using `diff -r`. However, this has crashed for large folders, maybe due to the lack of memory.

```
diff -r /path/to/ext4 /path/to/zfs
```

If both folders are identical, the `diff` is empty.